# How to show result on different view controller in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 `UIViewControllers` and I have `UIButtons` in the first 2 `UIViewControllers`. I want do an addition math problem on the first two and then I want the results to display on the 3rd `UIViewController` on `resultLabel`.

There is a YES button and there is a NO button but when I press YES I want it to add a number with the given variable and move on to the next view controller and then do the same and display my result on the last view controller where I have the `resultLabel`. I already created the segues for all controllers, so that's done.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind uploading your project so we can take a closer look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do, is (if you have not already), link all the viewControllers into a navigation controller. Do this by selecting the starting one, and go to Editor >> Embed Int >> Naviagtion Controller. Next right click drag from the first view controller to the second, and select "push", then from the second to the third in the same way. Next in the first VC, add the following code

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if let exampleViewController: ExampleViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ExampleViewController {
}
```

Note that with exampleViewController, I mean the controller that you are segueing to. If you want to give the destination VC any information, you do

```
secondViewController.exampleVariable = exampleVariable2
```